# Creating a Stored Procedure in DocumentDB via powershell

Tags: powershell, stored-procedures, azure-cosmosdb

We can create an SP by getting the collection's self link like the below statement:

```
$procedure = $client.CreateStoredProcedureAsync($coll_list.SelfLink,$proc)
```

Can we create a stored procedure using Uri like in the below statement:

```
$procedure = $docClient.CreateStoredProcedureAsync($dbUri,$proc).Result
```

Also, how to take care of the default Indexing Policy that gets created using powershell? Right now it creates a custom indexing policy. I want to create a default indexing policy.